# Detect changes in observable using async

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am trying to call function `init()` when person property change. I am using async pipe in html so I want to run init function whenever their is any change in person object.

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  person: Observable= {fname: 'sam', lname: 'xyz'}; // this is sample value given
  
  ngOnInit() {
this.initFunc()
  }

initFunc(){
console.log(this.person.fname)
}

}
```

Comment: ngOnInit `this.initFunc()`

Comment: its a typo actually

Answer (score 1):

There is an ng hook called `ngOnChanges` for such situation this is called whenever there is a change detected

Or if u want to check detections then you can use `ChangeDetectorRef` and use the predefined `detechChanges()`

[ChangeDetectorRef](https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef)

Answer (score 0):

you need to subscribe observable in order to execute some code each time something new is emitted. Not sure also init the observable in that way is correct, you can use the of(object) operator to emit the value one time.
You can see here some example:
[enter link description here](https://rxjs.dev/guide/subscription)